# Karma Jasmine Tests with SpyOn run fine in browser, but error with 'is not declared writable or has no setter' on auto re-run when a change is made

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, spyon

I have a suite of tests that run completely fine in the console and during the first run after starting up the browser session (i.e. `karma start`). But once I make a change and the browser session auto runs the tests again I'm getting the error below:

```
Error: <spyOn> : mySpydMethod is not declared writable or has no setter
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
```

This is a basic skeleton of what I'm doing.

```
import { mySpydMethod } from "modules/api";

describe(testNumber + '. Component display', () => {

    it('the test name', async () => {

         spyOn(api, "mySpydMethod ").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve([]));

         const vm = new TestVueComponent({
             propsData: { showData: true}
         }).$mount();

         await Vue.nextTick();

         const $component = $(vm.$el);

         expect($component.find(".wrapper").length).toEqual(1);

         vm.$destroy();
     });
});
```

Again, in the console and on the first run in the browser it works just fine. If it get's re-run automatically then it errors on the Spy. Does anyone know what may be causing this issue?

Karma v6.4.2 |
karma-jasmine 4.0.2 |
karma-chrome-launcher: 3.2.0 |
puppeteer: 21.4.1